# Could someone help me understand hexadecimal representation of files?

Tags: hex

I want to be able to manipulate the hexadecimal representation of a given file (without the use of a 3rd party application). Is the file representation just a series of hex digits in a specific order, or are they groups of a constant number of bytes of hex digits?

Comment: Can be done from powershell, some useful hex bits here.  http://www.sans.org/windows-security/2010/02/11/powershell-byte-array-hex-convert

Comment: Example using the Convert-functions from sans.org   `$readin = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\OldFile.exe");$hx = Convert-ByteArrayToHexString $readin -width 40 -delimiter "";$hx = $hx -replace "1234567890ABCDEF","FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";$hx = "0x" + $hx;$done = Convert-HexStringToByteArray $hx;set-content -value $done -encoding byte -path "C:\NewFile.exe";`

Comment: above snip reads in oldilfe.exe as bytes, uses sans.org function to convert to hex, replaces hex 123456..., with all FFFFFFF's, converts back into bytes and writes to newfile.exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hexadecimal is not a file format, it is a view of the contents of the file. Hex editors open up regular files and give you a view of the contents of the file with each byte represented by pairs of hexadecimal digits instead of letters, numbers, control characters et al.

You cannot view files in hexadecimal mode without an application to do so, any more than you can open up a text file to view it without a program like Notepad. If you are using Windows, there are no "first-party" hex editors available so you will just have to do it the way everyone always has unless you wish to program your own.

Comment: Characters may be represented by anywhere from two to eight hex digits (ASCII and the more common Unicode encodings). It's more correct to say "each **byte** represented by pairs of hexadecimal digits..."

Comment: Yeah, edited to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the hostility, thats why I asked about the 'representation' of the file. But you did answer my question so thank you.